# c++ simple way of read char and int from user input

Tags: c++, input

I would like to ask the user to input at least one character and maybe also a int value, and then read this (ignoring whitespaces). If the inputed data is not formatted correctly, I would like to throw an error. What would be the simplest way of achieving this?

Example:

```
 > Enter character and number:

(1) b     //should be fine (without space)
(2) b     //should also be fine (with space after b, "b ")
(3) b 1   //should also be fine
(4) b 1 n //should not be ok
(5) b b   //should not be ok
```

I've used something like this:

```
cout << "Enter a character and number: ";
cin >> myChar;
if (cin.peek() == ' ')
  cin >> myInt;
if (myInt < 1)
  {
    throw myError;
    myInt = 1;
  }
```

But it cannot handle b b entry. or the "b " entry.

This seems like a fairly easy and common problem, but I've been unable to find a clean solution for this.. 
Is there a "standard method" for reading multiple parameters from a user, with a predefined order of datatypes?

Assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: This is a very small part of larger computer excercise, apparently it is proper conduct to inform about such things.

So I ended up using the string parsing suggestion. Solution still seems overly complex though. I will leave it down below in case anyone stumbles upon this thread.

```
getline(cin, inputString);
istringstream iss(inputString);
iss >> myChar;
iss.peek(); // needed to trigger EOF. 
if (iss.fail())
    throw myError("unexpected error\n");
if (iss.eof())
    myInt = 1;
else
{
    iss >> myInt;
    if (iss.fail())
        throw myError("Incorrect input, no int\n");
    ws(iss);
    if (!iss.eof())
        throw myError("Incorrect input, not end of line.\n");
}
cin.clear();
```

Comment: What's the relationship between `index` and `myInt`?

Comment: Sounds like homework. You should state that it is if it is. You wouldn't want your prof. knowing that you cheated, right?

Comment: Either use [regular expressions (C++11)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) or read the data into a string and do the parsing yourself

Comment: myInt and index should've been the same, missed it when I tried to generalize things. Updated the topic. Also clearified that this is for school work.

Comment: @0x499602D2 You can use `std::istringstream` to do the parsing (although I too think that regular expressions would be easier).  Once you've got the line, read the character, check that that worked.  Then read the `int`: that should either work, or fail with the `eofbit` set; if it fails without seeing end of file, he's in case 5, above.  Finally, skip whitespace, and verify that that leaves you at end of file.

Comment: It usually helps if you tell us exactly what incorrect output you get on your failing test cases. I would guess that it hangs on the "b " entry, but what happens for "b b"? Does it process 'b' as 98?